# Tumblr back to top button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly familiar with HTML and CSS, but for the life of me i cannot get this 'back to top' button to work on my tumblr page. I would really appreciate a keen eye to help me out here. I have added a JQuery code to enable the text to fade in and out when scrolling (infinite scroll past 100).

Thanks very much for your help.

L

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}
<link href='http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/DHIm5wmgi/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



        <meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="color:Text" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="color:Video Corner Fold" content="red">
        <meta name="font:Font" content="'BrownBold'">
        <meta name="if:Show Captions" content="0"/>
        <meta name="if:Uppercase Links" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Fade On Hover" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Show Tags on Index Page" content="0">
        <meta name="image:header" content="0"/>

<style type="text/css">

#header {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background: url('{image:header}')no-repeat;
 position:fixed;
 margin: 15px 50% 0 50%;
 top:0px;
 left: -300px;
 right: -300px;
 z-index:9999;
}



body {
background-color:{color:Background};
font-family:{font:Font};
color:{color:Text};
font-size:17px;
line-height:25px;
}
a { 
padding-bottom:2px;
color:{color:Text};
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:2px solid;
}
img {
border: none;
border : 0;
outline:none;
}
a img {
outline: none;
}
iframe#tumblr_controls {  
display:none;
}
#wrapper {
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:580px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
position:relative;
margin: 50px auto; 
}
#post {
padding:40px;
}
#post img {
width:100%;
}
#post img:hover {
{block:IndexPage}
{block:IfFadeOnHover}
opacity:0.5;
{/block:IfFadeOnHover}
{/block:IndexPage}
}
#post embed, #post iframe {
width:100% !important;
}
#post .photoset a:first-child {
display:block !important;
border:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
}
#post .photoset a {
display:none;
}
.title {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
position:fixed;
top:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.follow {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 30% 0 16.3%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.archive {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 20px 0 30%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.message {
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.random {
position:fixed;
margin: 0px 0px 0 60%;
bottom:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
#toTop {
width:100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0 43%;
z-index:5000;
position:fixed;
display:none;
bottom:20px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.player {
background:#000;
}
ul.chat {
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#infscr-loading {
display:none !important;
}

.corner {
top:6px;
right:40px;
position:absolute;
padding:1em 1.5em;
margin:2em auto;
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:4000;
}
.corner:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
border-width:0 25px 25px 0;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#fff #fff {color:Video Corner Fold} {color:Video Corner Fold};
background:#fff;
display:block; width:0; /* Firefox 3.0 damage limitation */
}
{CustomCSS}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/4Wjm5wj58/disassemble_v3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();    
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>

{block:IfUppercaseLinks}<div style="text-transform:uppercase">{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}
<div class="title"><a href="/">{Title}</a></div>
<div class="archive"><a href="archive">Archive</a></div>
<div class="message"><a href="/ask">Message</a></div>
<div class="follow">{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Posts}<a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">Reblog</a> / {/block:Posts}{/block:PermalinkPage}<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/follow/{Name}">Follow</a></div>
<div class="random"><a href="/random">Random</a></div>
<div id="toTop">Back to top</div>
{block:IfUppercaseLinks}</div>{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}



<div id="wrapper">

{block:Posts}
<div id="post" 
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Post1}style="width:380px"{/block:Post1}
{block:Post2}style="width:410px"{/block:Post2}
{block:Post3}style="width:500px"{/block:Post3}
{block:Post4}style="width:290px"{/block:Post4}
{block:Post5}style="width:320px"{/block:Post5}
{block:Post6}style="width:460px"{/block:Post6}
{block:Post7}style="width:530px"{/block:Post7}
{block:Post8}style="width:280px"{/block:Post8}
{block:Post9}style="width:340px"{/block:Post9}
{block:Post10}style="width:400px"{/block:Post10}
{block:Post11}style="width:260px"{/block:Post11}
{block:Post12}style="width:370px"{/block:Post12}
{block:Post13}style="width:520px"{/block:Post13}
{block:Post14}style="width:310px"{/block:Post14}
{block:Post15}style="width:250px"{/block:Post15}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}style="width:500px"{/block:PermalinkPage}
> 

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>
{block:Description}<div class="description">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}

{block:Quote}
<a style="border:0 !important" href="{Permalink}">"{Quote}"</a>
{block:Source}
<p>&mdash; {Source}</p>
{/block:Source}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"  alt="{PhotoAlt}" border="0"/></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></div>{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">{block:Lines}<li class="user_{UserNumber}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}</li>{/block:Lines}</ul>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="corner"></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}
<div id="video"> 
{Video-500}
</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Video}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="photoset">{block:Photos}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"></a>{/block:Photos}</div>{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Audio}
{block:AlbumArt}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}"></a>{/block:AlbumArt}
<div class="player">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Audio}

{block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:Date}Posted {TimeAgo} and has {NoteCountWithLabel}{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Date}{/block:IndexPage}{/block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}Posted {TimeAgo} and has {NoteCountWithLabel}{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}

</div>
{/block:Posts}

{block:NextPage}<div id="page-nav"><a href="{NextPage}"></a>{/block:NextPage}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#header` element sits above `.archive`, `#toTop` and `.random` due to its higher `z-index` (5000 / 9999).

If you make the following change, `#toTop` is clickable and works as desired:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://static.tumblr.com/e72d71d9df861d718427e82229f48499/yo2ke79/iMEn5bbly/tumblr_static_9kpmrzvkfosoo4o0g8k4g80oc.png')no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 15px 50% 0 50%;
  top: 0px;
  left: -300px;
  right: -300px;
  z-index: 4999;
}
```

There is another error though. It seems two versions of jQuery are being requested:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

The later, `http://masonry.desandro.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js`, fails as it can't be found. I can't see why you need two versions of jQuery or why you are hot linking.

Either use a CDN (like the first link) or upload the javascript directly to Tumblr's own CDN.

Comment: Brilliant, that works perfectly now. Thank you so much man, I really really appreciate your help. I'll learn from that for next time! Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Instead of messing around with `scrollTop`, just use a link.

```
<a href="#">Scroll to Top</a>
```

This will take you straight back to the top. Admittedly no animations but if you're just looking for basic functionality then it's perfect.

Comment: This doesn't scroll the page. It actually reloads it. You need to use javascript to make it scroll smoothly without reloading

Comment: You can see a nice [back to top scroll button here](http://192.254.245.38/~energy/html.diyg.com/Resource-GrantArticles-Glossary.html)

Comment: I would paste the code in an answer fir you but im on my mobile. Do it when i get home

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Most likely should have mentioned this before so apologies... http://symbolsofwealth.tumblr.com/ - this is my blog, as you can see, the 'back to top' button appears, but the link itself is not working. I'm cool with the aethstetics of the button itself, it's just the functionality I'm having trouble with.

Comment: But yeah, I like the smoothness and pace of the example you posted Chris, that's cool.

Comment: I wasnt showing you a button for asthetics. Look at my js fir the functionality